# execute command in Java and faking input file as object

Tags: java, exec

I try to execute this in java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execString);
```

execString is something like that:

```
String execString = "/path/to/program.jar -e embedded " + jsonString;
```

If I have "jsonString" like that:

```
/path/to/jsFile.json
```

everything works well.
But in my Java-program I have a jsonstring which is a jsonObject.toString() and I would like to give this as input to the program.jar without saving it as file. Is this possible?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on how your `program.jar` is implemented. If it requires a file as an input, then it has to be a file. If it, for example, can read stdin or allows for the whole contents to be specified as a parameter, then you could do that. 

Impossible to tell, without knowing what `program.jar` wants.

Comment: @Dima: Okay thank you. I don't really know how it is. But how could I do it, if it is allwoed that the whole content is the parameter? Because in my json-File are quotes etc.

Comment: quotes do not have any special meaning here. The only thing that does is spaces. To prevent your input from being split into multiple arguments, use the `.exec(String[])` flavor, rather than `.exec(String)`:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/path/to/program.jar", "-e", "embedded", jsonObject.toString});

Also, note that "program.jar" seems wrong: if you are trying to execute a jar file, it needs to be an argument to `java`, not a command by itself.

Comment: @Dima: thanks, I will try this. Yeah but it is an executable .jar ..it works like this

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your .toString() in quotes and then read it as an art in the main class in programming.jar

Comment: the program.jar is not written by me. I can't change this jar.

Comment: You are stuck with what program.jar specifies then